# Class 'WP_Session_Tokens' not found

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging

After migration from Linux to Windows server there is on  website fatal error in WordPress core. Debug log:

```
[22-Jul-2022 13:07:54 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Session_Tokens' not found in D:\Sites\subdoms\test\wp-includes\class-wp-user-meta-session-tokens.php:17
Stack trace:
#0 D:\Sites\subdoms\test\wp-settings.php(188): require()
#1 D:\Sites\subdoms\test\wp-config.php(105): require_once('D:\\Sites\\web_98...')
#2 D:\Sites\subdoms\test\wp-load.php(50): require_once('D:\\Sites\\web_98...')
#3 D:\Sites\subdoms\test\wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('D:\\Sites\\web_98...')
#4 D:\Sites\subdoms\test\index.php(17): require('D:\\Sites\\web_98...')
#5 {main}
thrown in D:\Sites\subdoms\test\wp-includes\class-wp-user-meta-session-tokens.php on line 17
```

Before migration was active W3 total cache. Could it be related?
I removed W3 total cache, class-wp-user-meta-session-tokens.php and other WordPress files seems correct.

Comment: Have you done a migration for the DB so file paths are updated from Linux to Windows?

Comment: Migration did webhosting, so do you think they did not DB migrated correctly and it caused this error?

Comment: Your migration is corrupt. It's not the database, it's the structure of the WordPress source code files. Unless you know a lot about how to do migrations and configure WordPress, you will have a VERY hard time fixing this yourself.  Ask your hosting provider to try again. Or fire them and get a competent one. And, before you deploy WordPress on a Windows server, be sure you have a very good reason why to do that.